# Find the indices of the unmatched parenthesis

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, stack

I have to write (in Java, but the language is not important) a function that takes a parenthesized expression (as a string) as input and returns a collection of the indices of all unmatched parenthesis.

The function has to use only a stack as auxiliary data structure.

Example:

```
Input: ”d(f(b)())o”
Return:[]

Input: ”**)**(d(f(b)())) **)** o **(**”
Return:[0, 12, 14]
```

What's the right algorithm to resolve this problem?

Comment: So the only way to solve this problem I is to use, in addition to the stack, another any structure (as a array)?

Comment: If you want to return the index of ALL unmatched parens, then yes, you'll need something like an array to store them in. If you want either the first unmatched or yes/no it is unmatched, you could do it without an array

Comment: Although, you could go use a stack as a horrible way of storing the info. In my answer, wherever you see `indices.append()` replace with `outputStack.push()`. That way all your values are still stored in a stack (`outputStack`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Stacks` are actually glorious for parenthesis matching. In pseudocode it would look something like

```
indices = []

for i->0, i<length(string), i++ do

    if string[i] == "(" then
        stack.push("(")
        indexStack.push(i)

    else if string[i] == ")" then
        if stack.size() < 1 then
            indices.append(i)
        else
            stack.pop()
            indexStack.pop()

while indexStack.size() > 0 do
     indices.append(indexStack.pop())
```

As for an explanation of how this works.

- Iterate through the string
- If the `char` is an open paren, push it on the stack
- If the `char` is a close paren, check to see if there are any open parens on the stack
- If there is an open paren, pop it from the stack (we've found a match); if not, we have an unmatched paren, record index
- At the end, if there are any parens left in stack, they are unmatched, pop indices off `indexStack`

EDIT: Sorry, didn't handle unmatched open parens

Answer (score 2):

You could...

1. Go from left to right, examining each character
2. If it is an open paranthesis add it to the stack. Add this number to a list.
3. If it is a closed parenthesis pop from the stack. If you cannot pop, then, add the current character index to the list.
4. If you can pop, then, remove the last index from the open parenthesis list.
5. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until you are done

You could have 2 lists one taking care of the open parenthesis and another one taking care of the closed parenthesis. This will make things easier when removing indices.

Comment: 6. Add everything left on the stack to the list.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but couldn't you do the same thing without the stack? Since the stack only contains open parens, it seems like just a counter would work.

Comment: @Dukeling: Shouldn't steps 2 and 3 take care of that?

Comment: @JoeF: I think that in this case you are right, however, *if* memory serves stacks are needed because this is usually done through a Final State Automaton.

Comment: I think there is a logic error with your statement 4. It should remove the end most index (the most recent pushed paren) because that's the one the close paren is being matched to.

Comment: @npinti I didn't read your post-edit answer properly. But I think just having a stack (of indices) seems simpler. I suppose either would work.